# Show one product with multiple quantity as one entry with Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce

I've been learning cart throb for about a month off and on and there's one functionality that seems to be missing. If I'm trying to purchase three black shirts I will use a quantity tag:

```
{exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form class='forms product-forms id{purchasable_products:entry_id} off' entry_id="{purchasable_products:entry_id}" no_tax="{no_tax}"}

                <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{count}]" value="{entry_id}" />

                    {exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{purchasable_products:entry_id}"}

                        {select class='width-70 margin-bottom' limit="1"}
                            <option {selected} value="{option_value}">{option_value} {if option_price_numeric != 0} ({option_price}){/if}</option>
                        {/select}

                    {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}

                    <input type="text" class="product_quantity" name="quantity[{count}]" value="1">

                    </label>

                    <p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green add-to-cart" data-target="cart-update">Add to Cart</button>
                        <a href="/shopping/view-cart" class="btn btn-blue btn-disabled view-cart-button"><i class="icon icon-shopping-cart"></i>View Cart</a>
                        <a href="/shopping/checkout" class="btn btn-green btn-disabled checkout-button">Checkout</a>
                    </p>
                {/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
```

When I add those three items, they show in my cart as three separate entries rather than one entry with one quantity.

Which says items are added, but the cart total is $0.00 and still shows as multiple entires in the view cart page. View cart code is

```
{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info} 
    {product_photos limit='1'}
            <img src="{product_photos:photo}" alt="{product_photos:photo_title}">
    {/product_photos}
    <h3 class="pull-left">{title}</h3>
```

Which results in looped out items, but adds no money to the cart. My goal is to only show a single item, with its proper quantity and proper cart price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a settings in your CartThrob options, I don't have the latest version of CT installed but should be able to goto CartThrob > Products > Product Options > Split multiple quantities into single items. In your case you would probably want "No".

From the cartthrob_lang.php file since I don't think it is mentioned in their docs:

> If your prodcts can be configured with unique options (like color,
>   shape, size, personalization) set this to "yes." Normally, if your
>   products do not have configuration options, setting this to "no" add
>   quantiy if "add to cart" is used multiple times on the same product.
>   If this is set to "yes" each time "add to cart" is used on one product
>   a completely new product will be added to the cart.

Since it appears you are only adding a single item to the cart you would be perfectly fine using the [add_to_cart_form](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart_form/index.html) instead of the multi.

Your view cart_items_info tag does not look complete which would cause some issues with proper outputting. I think you are interested in the `{exp:cart throb:cart_total}` or `{exp:cart throb:cart_subtotal}` tags among others to show the actual cart value along side of `{exp:cart throb:cart_items_info}` tag pair.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address the second portion of your question.

Comment: Brilliant! In the latest version the nav tree looks like CartThrob > Products then scroll to the bottom to find "Product Options." From there you'll see "Split multiple quantities into single items" and select "no."

Comment: Glad that I was able to help.